# How can kubernetes autoscale using HPA with metric server?

Tags: kubernetes

I am very interesed in testing kubernete auto-scale solution in Ubuntu installation. I already used it in minikube, with heapster, but since it is deprecated already, I tried to use metric server.
Now in my Ubuntu, I installed metrics-server like below:

```
kube-system      kube-apiserver-kmaster                  1/1     Running   1          11d
kube-system      kube-controller-manager-kmaster         1/1     Running   1          11d
kube-system      kube-proxy-47k6b                        1/1     Running   0          11d
kube-system      kube-proxy-q8zdw                        1/1     Running   1          11d
kube-system      kube-scheduler-kmaster                  1/1     Running   1          11d
kube-system      kubernetes-dashboard-5f7b999d65-6wl6k   1/1     Running   1          11d
kube-system      metrics-server-548456b4cd-wxc9b         1/1     Running   0          3d18h
metallb-system   controller-cd8657667-ckpn6              1/1     Running   0          8d
metallb-system   speaker-m9599
```

But when I check HPA I always saw below:

Kubectl get hpa

```
NAME         REFERENCE               TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
api-server   Deployment/api-server   <unknown>/50%   1         10        3          3d19h
ngsc         Deployment/ngsc         <unknown>/50%   1         10        3          3d19h
```

Seemed metric service is not used for calculating the usage.

I went to Kubernetes doc site, and really can not figure out how to config the utilization for the metric-server so that Kubernetes do the auto-scale.

I describe the auto-scale:

```
                        api-server
Namespace:                                             default
Labels:                                                <none>
Annotations:                                           <none>
CreationTimestamp:                                     Fri, 03 May 2019 05:49:07 +0000
Reference:                                             Deployment/api-server
Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  <unknown> / 50%
Min replicas:                                          1
Max replicas:                                          10
Deployment pods:                                       3 current / 0 desired
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason                   Message
  ----           ------  ------                   -------
  AbleToScale    True    SucceededGetScale        the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
  ScalingActive  False   FailedGetResourceMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                        From                       Message
  ----     ------                   ----                       ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric  4m48s (x22069 over 3d20h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
```

Describe for deployment:

```
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=api-server
  Containers:
   api-server:
    Image:      xxxxxx
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Limits:
      cpu:  500m
    Requests:
      cpu:        200m
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
```

This means the deployment has the resource cofiguration. But still hpa shows unknown

Add memory, now describe is:

```
 Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:        500m
      memory:     512Mi
```

But kubectl get hpa is still unknown.

Checking logs for the metrics-server:

```
 1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:kmaster: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet kmaster (kmaster): Get https://kmaster:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup kmaster on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host, unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:knode: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet knode (knode): Get https://knode:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup knode on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host]
E0507 05:20:23.797590       1 reststorage.go:148] unable to fetch pod metrics for pod default/api-server-777b78ccf5-mlt94: no metrics known for pod
E0507 05:20:23.797614       1 reststorage.go:148] unable to fetch pod metrics for pod default/api-server-777b78ccf5-r66bw: no metrics known for pod
```

And when

```
curl -k https://knode:10250/stats/summary/`
```

I got this error:

```
Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on information you provided.

As you have pod `metrics-server-548456b4cd-wxc9b` it's mean that metric-server is enabled. Also as you have 3 replicas i assume this number was provided in Deployment manifest.

HPA might not scaled your deployment due to:

**1) Lack of resources**

```
$ kubectl describe node
...
 Namespace                  Name                                 CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                  ----                                 ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                    nginx-deployment-5ffb677f99-k5mdj    200m (10%)    500m (25%)  0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m55s
  default                    nginx-deployment-5ffb677f99-n7t7n    200m (10%)    500m (25%)  0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m55s
  default                    nginx-deployment-5ffb677f99-pw2g7    200m (10%)    500m (25%)  0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m55s
  kube-system                etcd-minikube                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         152m
  kube-system                kube-addon-manager-minikube          5m (0%)       0 (0%)      50Mi (0%)        0 (0%)         152m
  kube-system                kube-apiserver-minikube              250m (12%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         152m
  kube-system                kube-controller-manager-minikube     200m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         152m
  kube-system                kube-dns-6bfbdd666c-l74lx            260m (13%)    0 (0%)      110Mi (1%)       170Mi (2%)     32m
  kube-system                kube-proxy-dnh4m                     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         153m
  kube-system                kube-scheduler-minikube              100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         152m
  kube-system                metrics-server-77fddcc57b-mjlf5      0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         147m
  kube-system                storage-provisioner                  0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         153m
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests     Limits
  --------           --------     ------
  cpu                1415m (70%)  1500m (75%)
  memory             160Mi (2%)   170Mi (2%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)       0 (0%)
```

As you see on the example, minikube resources and 3 pods with nginx already requested 70% of the CPU. 
In your manifest each container will request `cpu: 200m` so this deployment can create only 2 more pods. Others pods will be on `Pending` state due to lack of CPU resources.

**2) Lack of CPU Load**

Error message like `the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API` means that metric-server did not receive any metrics so pods did not generate any load.

I assume you scaled deployment using command

```
$ kubectl autoscale deployment api-server --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10
...
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason                   Message
  ----           ------  ------                   -------
  AbleToScale    True    SucceededGetScale        the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
  ScalingActive  False   FailedGetResourceMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age   From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----  ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       9s    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  9s    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
```

Try generate some CPU load by entering one of the deployments pod

```
$ kubectl exec -ti <yourPodName> sh

$ while true; do echo 'IncreaseLoad'; done
IncreaseLoad
IncreaseLoad
IncreaseLoad
...
```

You can also use `stress` command.

After a while HPA should get metrics and change from  to correct value.

```
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason              Message
  ----            ------  ------              -------
  AbleToScale     True    ReadyForNewScale    recommended size matches current size
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound    the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from cpu resource utilization (percentage of request)
  ScalingLimited  False   DesiredWithinRange  the desired count is within the acceptable range
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age                From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----               ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       14m (x6 over 16m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  14m (x6 over 16m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
  Normal   SuccessfulRescale             6m54s              horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 2; reason: All metrics below target
  Normal   SuccessfulRescale             50s                horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 4; reason: cpu resource utilization (percentage of request) above target
```

If this didnt help please provide your HPA and Deployment manifests.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens HPA is not showing the value make sure pod of metrics server is running inside namespace kube-system.

With me sometimes it happens when traffic comes on the website it starts showing the values in HPA.

Comment: besides making metric-server running inside kube-system, any other thing I need to make to let auto-scale work?

Comment: I donot anything else is needed you can try generating direct using 'busybox' and check it's working on not.

Comment: I hope you have added resources in yaml file. include cpu and memory.

Answer (score 0):

That means that pods does not have any cpu resources assigned to them. Without resources assigned HPA cannot make scaling decisions. Try adding some resources to pods like this:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```